# Wordpress Rewrite stops working on php 7.2

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone help me? This rewrite rule works on PHP 5.6, but no longer works on PHP 7.2 for odd reason. No PHP errors whatsoever its just white blank space.

Currently using Wordpress 5.1 as well.

```
/* adds the post name and the post id to the permalink structure of a listing */
function listing_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $queryarg = 'post_type=listing&p=';
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%list_id%', '([^/]+)', $queryarg);
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('listing', '/%postname%-L%list_id%/', false);
}


/* add the post name and the post id to the url for a listing */
function listing_permalink($post_link, $id = 0, $leavename, $sample) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if (get_post_type($id) == "listing") {
        $post = &get_post($id);
        if ( is_wp_error( $post ) )
            return $post;
        $newlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct('listing');
        $newlink = str_replace("%list_id%", $post->ID, $newlink);
        $newlink = str_replace("%postname%", $post->post_name, $newlink);
        $newlink = home_url(user_trailingslashit($newlink));
        return $newlink;
    }
    return $post_link;
}

/* rewrite the urls to remove 'listing' and add -L%post_id% at the end */
add_action('init', 'listing_rewrite');
add_filter('post_type_link', 'listing_permalink', 1, 20);
```

Comment: *"No PHP errors whatsoever its just white blank space."* ... that *normally* means it's a fatal error - you're just not displaying it.

Comment: I'm assuming the comment which would be a syntax error is a copy and paste mistake rather than your actual code?  (3 lines from the bottom)

Comment: good catch, but it was properly commented in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'listing_permalink', 1, 20);
```

to

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'listing_permalink', 1, 4);
```

You are currently suggesting that the callback will accept 20 arguments when it will actually only accept 4. These are supposed to match. (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).